# Wait until download finishes

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code:

```
    Action<int, ProgressBar, Label, Label, int, Button> downloadFileAsync = (i, pb, label2, label1, ServID, button1) =>
    {
        var bd = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var fn = bd + "/" + i + ".7z";
        var down = new WebClient();
        DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler dpc = (s, e) =>
        {
            label1.Text = "Download Update: " + i + " / " + ServID;
            int rec =Convert.ToInt16(e.BytesReceived / 1024);
            int total =Convert.ToInt16(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024)  ;
            label2.Text = "Downloaded: " + rec.ToString() + "KB / " + total.ToString() + " KB";
            pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        };
        AsyncCompletedEventHandler dfc = null;  dfc = (s, e) =>
        {
            label1.Text = "Extracting Files...";
            Rar Ra = new Rar();
            Ra.Open(i + ".7z");
            Ra.Unrar(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            File.Delete(fn);
            down.DownloadProgressChanged -= dpc;
            down.DownloadFileCompleted -= dfc;
            down.Dispose();
            if (ServID == i)
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
                label1.Text = "Have Fun In-Game...";
                label2.Text = "Done...";
            }
        };
        down.DownloadProgressChanged += dpc;
        down.DownloadFileCompleted += dfc;
        down.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://unknowndekaron.net/updatee/" + i + "/" + i + ".7z"), fn);
    };
```

And This is My Call:

```
                while (i <= ServID)
                {
                    downloadFileAsync(i, progressBar1, label2, label1, ServID, button1);
                    i++;
                }
```

Decompress:

```
    public void Decompress(int i)
    {

        Rar Ra = new Rar();
        Ra.Open(i + ".7z");
        Ra.Unrar(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

    }
```

In this code program downloads all the updates at once...
It starts to decomprees the first one which's download is completed completed.
I need the app to download only one update at once and then decompreeses it.

Comment: What are you having trouble doing? What problems are you running in to trying to do this your self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unelegant solution with using booleans:

You should move the top level lambda into new `async` method. You can call it in while normaly. After that declare boolean `downloadCompleted` on the start of your top level lambda and set it to false. Then go to `AsyncCompletedEventHandler` and at the end set the value of `downloadCompleted` to true - this will signalize the last while loop that we have finished. End of top level lamba should wait until fullfillment of downloading and compressing. This won't change the state of the application to "not responding".

**Example**

Call:

```
    downloadFileAsync = (i, pb, label2, label1, ServID, button1) =>
    {
        Download(i, pb, label2, label1, ServID, button1);
    };
```

New method:

```
    public async Task<int> Download(...)
    {
        bool downloadCompleted = false;
        var bd = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var fn = bd + "/" + i + ".7z";
        var down = new WebClient();
        DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler dpc = (s, e) =>
        {
            label1.Text = "Download Update: " + i + " / " + ServID;
            int rec = Convert.ToInt16(e.BytesReceived / 1024);
            int total = Convert.ToInt16(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024);
            label2.Text = "Downloaded: " + rec.ToString() + "KB / " + total.ToString() + " KB";
            pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        };
        AsyncCompletedEventHandler dfc = null; dfc = (s, e) =>
        {
            label1.Text = "Extracting Files...";
            Rar Ra = new Rar();
            Ra.Open(i + ".7z");
            Ra.Unrar(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            File.Delete(fn);
            down.DownloadProgressChanged -= dpc;
            down.DownloadFileCompleted -= dfc;
            down.Dispose();
            if (ServID == i)
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
                label1.Text = "Have Fun In-Game...";
                label2.Text = "Done...";
            }
            downloadCompleted = true;
        };
        down.DownloadProgressChanged += dpc;
        down.DownloadFileCompleted += dfc;
        down.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://unknowndekaron.net/updatee/" + i + "/" + i + ".7z"), fn);
        while (!downloadCompleted)
            ;
    }
```

Calling while loop can stay as it is.

Comment: I need c# 5 for public async??

Comment: tnx man i mannge to get this to work..